# Binding to a property by variable name (ideally from xaml)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to databind (ideally from XAML as i know how to do this in code behind but it would be far from trivial to traverse my heavily templated tree just for that) to a property who's name i only know at runtime
What i would like to do is not the usual:

```
Content="{Binding TheProperty}"
```

But something like

```
Content="{Binding PropertyName=TheNameIsStoredInThisProperty}"
```

I'm trying to do this because i generate the UI from templates when binding to my plugins, but the UI is specified in a set of POCO and separate from the ViewModel, so i want to be able to generate my UI and still be able to wire it to the correct properties on the ViewModel, any advice is most welcome.

Comment: I had the same problem.  Are you using Unity?  I ask because the recent release of Unity allows you to add INotifyPropertyChanged to a POCO without disturbing any code in the POCO or adding anything to it.  In fact, the POCO is totally unaware of it.  Using Unity, the VM gets the change notifications and can update the UI via its own PropertyChanged.

Comment: No not using Unity, using my own code only, i just need a generic way to bind to a property whose name i only know at runtime from XAML

Comment: Fair enough, did you consider binding to an arbitrary property and using IValueConverter Convert/ConvertBack with some Reflection to invoke the value of the named property?

Comment: I'm fearing this would end up being quite slow, it's for a fairly heavy UI with lots of forced updates (dozens of commands and bindings, some requiring re triggering everything at once).

Comment: However if there are no other clean alternatives (i hoped for a markup extention or maybe an out of the box solution that existed and i wasn't aware of) this will actually be a pretty decent workaround i guess, at least it is a workaround at all unlike what i had come up with :)

Comment: There's probably 100 ways to do it.  A markup extension could provide the value but if all you have is a name (in a string) you will need to Reflect anyway.  It's down to your personal style I guess

Comment: Aye i meant one that existed (i mean WPF uses reflection for regular databinding, i just kinda hoped not to do it myself and have the, i assume, good performance and caching mechanism WPF uses internally instead of trying to match it myself). Btw you should repost it as an answer, unless someone comes up with something i didn't know of or a third party solution i can buy or a library i can just include, this is likely to be the accepted answer.

Comment: I can repost my comments, but do you need the Reflection stuff as c#?

Comment: No i can do it just fine, feel free to post something if you think it could help others looking for the same thing, i just didn't think of the valueconverter solution earlier

Comment: I will post it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate solution might be to bind to an arbitrary property in your VM with an IValueConverter that goes both ways, and the ConverterParameter is the string containing the source property name.  Once inside the value converter you can use an interception pattern to Reflect out the value you need from the POCO.  You can then pass the value up to the source property in the VM.  Rather like a pipeline :)  This will work but still leaves you with being notified when the POCO changes.

A Markup Extension seems plausible but likely to be brittle and provide naught in the way of performance improvement.

An Attached Behaviour still leaves you with having to Reflect and does not easily solve the problem of notifications originating in the POCO (AFAIK only Unity knows how to do that).

Comment: Just to be clear INotifyPropertyChanged / notifications are not a concern at all (the POCO hierarchy never changes, it's a one time thing, but i want to describe on those poco, which describe the compnent tree, where the components bind to the actual viewmodel)

Comment: So the ValueConverter way works, but the Unity comments are not really relevant to the problem

Comment: That means you're home free!  All the best and shout if there's problems.

Comment: Doesn't seem like anyone will chime in with a better solution, so answer accepted, thanks for the workaround :)

Comment: Thanks, please let me know what strategy you used because I have practitioner's interest in the area of binding